# CMS + Ecommerce - Which opensource program is best?

Tags: content-management-system, e-commerce

We have to develop an Ecommerce site with 20+ pages of static content which needs a CMS and a store or 30+ products. 
We use Magento or Cubecart for Ecommerce and Wordpress or Joomla for CMS sites.

Which has the best of both worlds - a good CMS with Store management? I am not sure if a Wordpress CMS site with an Shopping cart plugin will be a scalable solution.. Any advice?

Comment: you should probably accept some of the answers, if you find that it answers your question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress with e-Commerce plugin seems to be a simple and elegant solution: http://www.instinct.co.nz/e-commerce/
Joomla with VirtueMart is a fairly feature heavy combination: http://virtuemart.net/

Comment: It should be mentioned that VirtueMart is also extremely buggy, hard to use, and you will have to spend a lot of time customizing it if you want a decent store. If I had to use it again, I wouldn't.

Answer (score 6):

I would use Magento, it is based on the Zend Framework and it is the best PHP solution, well documented, OO.

Comment: I hear that Magento is pretty difficult to customize and that the Zend Framework adds a sharper learning curve. Just my notion based on different posts here at Stackoverflow.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511414/magento-developers-is-magento-really-that-good , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062032/ubercart-vs-drupal-commerce-vs-magento/3220051#3220051 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363774/magento-or-prestashop-which-is-better/1606236#1606236

Answer (score 5):

I'm a big fan of [Drupal](http://drupal.org) for a full-featured CMS, and though it has a bit of learning curve, it's worth it for its flexibility and power.  Its [e-Commerce module](http://drupal.org/project/ecommerce) is excellent as well, and integrates nicely to create online stores.  Both are totally free, open-source goodness, with a large, supportive community.

Comment: +1 for Drupal, though I'd use uber cart instead of e-commerce.

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems you're already comfortable with Joomla and since your store is pretty small, you might want to simply add an E-Comm extension:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e%252dcommerce

Answer (score 2):

There's a new product called [Caribou CMS](http://www.cariboucms.com) which is a content management system (CMS) with e-commerce functionality (online storefront, subscriptions, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I generally prefer to use the open source [DashCommerce](http://dashcommerce.org/).  I have installed and use this across many small sites and I get nothing but rave reviews for it.  The key here is that non-technical people are able to get around in it and manage the content without any problem at all.  And it is great for geeks too in that you have full access to everything...read - tweak till your hearts content!

Comment: Let's try and promote our own book with a link that looks like something else?  I don't even know where to begin with how little respect that deserves...

Comment: I fixed the link. Could have just been a honest mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can check:

http://dashcommerce.org/ free

http://www.dotshoppingcart.com/ free

http://www.nopcommerce.com/ free

http://www.storefront.net/ buy

And based on your needs you can select.

And for a complete list of most of exist CMS systems check this website: **http://cmsmatrix.org/**

Answer (score 1):

[ExpressionEngine](http://www.expressionengine.com) is an extremely flexible professional CMS. It has a Multiple Site Manager and robust integrated e-commerce solutions like [BrilliantRetail](http://www.brilliantretail.com). We have used it to do everything from intranets to enterprise commerce and it scales very well. EE also has a great collection of quality extensions (devot-ee) and an active twitter community (#eecms).

Answer (score 0):

It's not open source, but I'd recommend checking out Verb CMS (http://verbcms.com/), which is a hosted CMS service with fully integrated eCommerce.  It's super cool.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/)**. You can have both **CMS and Ecommerce** facility in it.

> Magento eCommerce Platforms provide
>   the scalability, flexibility and
>   features for business growth. Magento
>   provides feature-rich eCommerce
>   platforms that offer merchants
>   complete flexibility and control over
>   the presentation, content, and
>   functionality of their online channel.
>
> The Magento Community Edition is
>   available as a free download under the
>   open source OSL 3.0 license and is
>   recommended for expert developers and
>   highly technical enthusiasts and
>   hobbyists in non-mission critical
>   environments.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.ror-e.com  it has a double entry accounting system, purchase orders, inventory management, shopping cart (with save for later and wish list) shipments, returns, coupons, customer credits.  check out the video http://www.ror-e.com/info/videos/1

All build with ruby on rails 3.